# Using JavaFX in a SWT Project?

Tags: java, audio, swt, javafx-2

I'm doing a desktop project which I want to run cross platform preferably. The project will be done 99.99% in SWT, however for one part, i.e playing Mp3s (which can be long) I want to use JavaFx's new MediaPlayer class, since it makes it a lot easy to change volume, seek to a different part in the mp3, get the current time in the mp3, get the total length of the mp3, etc.

Is it possible to build everything as an SWT project, but include the bare minimum to make the JavaFX's MediaPlayer class work? If so, what do I need to include? I'm using Netbeans as the IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaFX 2 supports SWT interoperability. You can use `javafx.embed.swt.FXCanvas` to draw any FX nodes in SWT application.

See here in details: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swt_interoperability/jfxpub-swt_interoperability.htm